# What is the purpose of the bracketed START/END comments in this google code?

Tags: python, comments

From [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/compute/api/create_instance.py):

```
# [START list_instances]
def list_instances(compute, project, zone):
    result = compute.instances().list(project=project, zone=zone).execute()
    return result['items'] if 'items' in result else None
# [END list_instances]
```

Can anyone tell me what these are for? They look like editor hints, or perhaps some auto-documentation thing, but I was not able to find information about it.

Comment: It is a comment... the prupose is to have some sort of code explanation...

Comment: It looks like it's just that programmer's personal style.

Comment: The online documentation seems to use those tags to know which parts of the file to embed. You don't need to do anything like that in your code.

Comment: For example, DOM inspection shows the Python sample [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#publicimage) has `data-github-path="GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/compute/api/create_instance.py"` and `data-region-tag="create_instance"`, and it embeds the part of `create_instance.py` delimited by `# [START create_instance]` and `# [END create_instance]`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "user2357112 supports Monica" has the correct answer - the (Google-internal) documentation system seems to use these section boundaries to extract relevant code samples into the documentation.